# How to get value from an optional object in another optional?

Tags: java, option-type

Basically,I need to get a size of optional list in an optional object. Something like:

```
private int getCount(@NonNull Optional<myObject> aaa) {
    if(aaa.isPresent() && aaa.get().getMyList().isPresent()) {
        return aaa.get().getMyList().get().size();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code doesn't look nice. What's the elegant way to get it? With ifPresent().orElse()?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"elegant way"* -> probably none - it is kind of *strange* having an `Optional` as parameter (and maybe same having one as attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consecutive `map` (or `flatMap`, in case something returns an `Optional`) operations, and a final `orElse`:

```java
private int getCount(@NonNull Optional<myObject> cvm) {
    return cvm
      .flatMap(x -> x.getMyList())
      .map(list -> list.size()) // or List::size
      .orElse(0);
}
```